# Failed to load PDF document using mpdf 6.1

Tags: html, codeigniter, google-chrome, pdf, mpdf

I'm using codeigniter in my system and mpdf 6.1 to generate pdf. I get an error in chrome '**Failed to load PDF document**' every time when I open new tab to preview. What's wrong with that? My code in html to print:

```
include_once APPPATH . 'third_party/mPDF/mpdf.php';

$title= 'customer';
$html .= '<html>';
$html .= '<body>';
$html .= '<table>';
$html .= '</table>';
$html .= '</body>';
$html .= '</html>';
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4', '', '', 10, 10, 55, 20, 10, 10);
$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->setTitle($title);
$mpdf->Output(url_title($title.'.pdf'), 'i');
```

Thank you :)

Comment: mPDF is a bit tricky... if you need to generate a PDF from an HTML doc, you'll have a much easier ride with dompdf. That said, the problem seems to be that your `$html` variable is being overwritten on each statement (each statement says `$html = 'something'` instead of appending/concatenating each statement to the previous ones (`$html .= 'something'` ... notice the period). Additionally, if you're using codeigniter, it's much more advisable to load a view in the variable (`$html = $this->load->view('viewname', true);` and then pass that to mpdf)

Comment: Thanks for answer me, oh i'm forget.. in my code i have been added $html .= but the result still same "failed to load PDF document"

Comment: See this https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/corrupt-pdf-file.html documentation page.